# Spring Injecting Bean Reference prints memory address instead of value

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have written a sample code to practise Spring Bean Injection using setter methods.
But in my output I get a memory address instead of the value I need (in List Element list as 1st element).

I think this is due to some error in ref bean="address1" declaration.

Appreciate if you can please help me in correcing this error

This is the output I get

List Elements: [**com.springtutorial.Address@1b6101e**, Clash of Kings, Storm of Swords, Feast for Crows, Dance with Dragons]
Address :Winterfell

This is the Bean Class Code

```
<bean id="javaCollection" class="com.springtutorial.JavaCollection">
    <property name="addressList">
        <list>
            <ref bean="address1"/>
            <value>Clash of Kings</value>
            <value>Storm of Swords</value>
            <value>Feast for Crows</value>
            <value>Dance with Dragons</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="address1" class="com.springtutorial.Address">
    <property name="address" value="Winterfell"/>
</bean>
```

This the Address Class Code

```
public class Address {

String address;

public String getAddress() {
    System.out.println("Address :"+address);
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
```

Java Collection class `public class JavaCollection {

```
List addressList;

public List getAddressList() {
    System.out.println("List Elements: " + addressList);
    return addressList;
}

public void setAddressList(List addressList) {
    this.addressList = addressList;
}

}
```

`

Main class is like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
    JavaCollection jc = (JavaCollection) ctx.getBean("javaCollection");
    Address obj = (Address) ctx.getBean("address1");

    jc.getAddressList();
    jc.getAddressSet();
    jc.getAddressMap();
    jc.getAddressProp();

    obj.getAddress();
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you missed to override the toString() method in Address, hence you are getting the default Output witch is the object identifier.

```
public String toString() {

    String stringX = //build String
    return stringX;
}
```

Note: optionaly you can add the @Override - at the top of the methods.
This has the following benefits:

- The compiler checks that you are really overriding a method.
- Other Programmers can easily see that you are overrding a method.

Even so it may be a bit redundent for a commonenly overriden method such as toString().

Other important methods that should commonly be overriden (but usually are forgotten) equals and toHashCode. It is important to override these for a variety of reasons explained [here](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/why-always-override-hashcode-if-overriding-equals/20).

Comment: Ok. How can I override the toString() method to fit in as you suggest. Can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: You just add the method to your Class public String toString() {...}

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a memory address, but rather the usual output of `Object.toString()`, which is the class name and the *hash code*.

Spring expects your `List` to contains `String` instances, but you're attempting to add an `Address`.  Spring simply calls `toString` on the `Address` to make it "fit" in the collection.

You're not declaring your `List` as parameterized, but I suspect the presence of String value objects, e.g. `<value>Clash of Kings</value>`, is leading Spring to expect a `List<String>` instead.

If you haven't read up on it already, now might be a good time to read up on generics.